# Change image with animation in reused UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation, reusability

In my application I have a feed with posts. Each post is represented by a cell in `UITableView`. A post has two states: read or unread. Each cell has an `UIImageView`, which has to display different images based on this state. I set this imageView's image in my table controller's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

I also check visibility of cells while scrolling the table, and, when a cell becomes visible, it's state is changed, so cell's image is changed with animation. This animation, however, is not working properly when cell is reused. First cell to become visible is animated properly, but all cells after the first one already have resulting image when they appear on screen, animation is not fired for them. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
// This is called when a cell becomes visible
- (void)setIsVisible:(Boolean)isVisible
{

    if (isVisible)
    {         
        UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img-cell-read.png"];

        [UIView transitionWithView:self.myImageView
                          duration:2.0f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^{
                            self.myImageView.image = toImage;
                        } completion:NULL];
    }
_isVisible = isVisible;

}
```

I realize that I should somehow reset this animation and start it again when I'm reusing a cell, but I don't understand how exactly should I do it. Also, if I try to animate cell's background color instead of image, it works fine with reusing.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the prepareForReuse method in UITableViewCell to cancel any animations and also reset the image to the original state.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self.myImageView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    self.myImageView.image = YOUR_INITIAL_UIIMAGE;
}
```

also make sure to import quartz:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a little bit, most of the cells are animated properly now, but still some already have resulting image when they appear on screen.

Comment: but is it really recommended to use Quartzcore framework on UITableViewCell class which gets "reused" when scrolled?